# AWS CLI returns empty array when attempting to list Elastic Beanstalk applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I want to execute Elastic Beanstalk commands via the CLI. For starters, I want to list the applications in it like so:

```
aws --profile main --region us-east-1 elasticbeanstalk describe-applications
```

…but all I get is this:

```json
{
    "Applications": []
}
```

I double-checked the profile I'm using and the region - they are correct. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have the necessary permissions.

In a test account, I tried adding/removing the `elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications` action permission. When I have it, the applications are correctly listed. When I don't - I see the empty array.

It's interesting why I don't simply receive a permissions error…

**Edit:** I opened [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/435) and it turned out to be a bug.

Comment: Odd. I wonder if this is because Elastic Beanstalk historically had its own dedicated cli and this is deliberate to make the two compatible in some way.